# jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn functions are screwing up display properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my bit of JavaScript:

```
   comDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('comDiv');
   fillerRants = document.getElementsByClassName('filler2Rant');

   for (let y = 0; y < comDivs.length; y++) {
       $(comDivs[y]).delay(4000).fadeOut(400, function() {
         $(fillerRants[y]).fadeOut(400);
    });
       $(comDivs[y + 1]).delay(350).fadeIn(400, function() {
         $(fillerRants[y + 1]).fadeIn(400);
    });
   }
```

This is supposed to show every element of the comDiv class one at a time for four seconds, then fadeOut() the current element and fadeIn() the next element. For example, the first item would be the only one showing when the page loads. After four seconds, it fades out and the second element fades in. Prior to this loop running, all elements except the first one have been hidden. With the above code, when the page loads, for some reason ALL the elements show up, then fade out one at a time. I have tried multiple different solutions, but none of them worked. What is wrong? I will be happy to provide additional information if it is needed.